# Linked server Security remote login with password is giving error

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

When i try to add remote login archiver_IEX_New and password in security tab of linked server i get below error.
"No remote users 'archiver_IEX_New' from remote server 'ARCHIVDB' is assigned to the local users 'FARM \ Administrator'"

Comment: what version of MS SQL you are using? Can you provide screenshot of `New linked server` dialog?

Comment: i am using SQL Server 2012 version 11.0

Comment: archiver_IEX_New is windows user or user from MS SQL?

Comment: This is a new login i created on remote server 'ARCHIVDB'

Comment: This user have windows authentification ot SQL Server authentification?

Comment: Sql Sever Authentiacation